# JavaScript-CSS : Trouble getting Nav Menu to change from transparent to opaque on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I'm playing around with some design ideas and can't seem to get the JavaScript to do what I want it to. I want a transparent TopNav, that when the user scrolls to say 48px or wherever I deem the TopNav background goes black. Crude Example below of what I want to happen, but when i scroll the TopNav just stays transparent. I've tried a couple of solutions from other answers here to the point of copy/paste and just edit the element names to match my html. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong: 
[image: Start]

[image: Scroll]

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Futura, Arial, Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
}

header {
    margin: 0;
}
.stickyNav {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
}
.topNav {
    max-width: 1366px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: #D4D4D4;
    height: 48px;
}
.scroll {
    background-color:#000000;
}
.navigationMenu{
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
var myNav = document.getElementById("TopNav");

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 1) {
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else {
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<header >
    <div class="stickyNav" >
        <nav class="topNav" id="TopNav">
            <h3>LOGO HERE</h3>
            <ul class="navigationMenu">
                <li class="navigationItem">Home</li>
                <li class="navigationItem">Services</li>
                <li class="navigationItem">About</li>
                <li class="navigationItem">Contact</li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

> can't seem to get the JavaScript to do what I want it to

This is a matter of CSS styling - not Javascript. The Javascript job in this code is just to detect scroll and add or remove the class.

So if you want the default background to be transparent do one of these:

```
.topNav { background-color: transparent; } // transparent
.topNav { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); } // transparent
```

and after adding a class to have a background, do:

```
.topNav.scroll { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); }} // 50% black, "semi-transparent"
```

Comment: I did the above, and got nothing. The navigation just stays transparent. I used rgba(0,0,0,0) and rgba(0,0,0,.5) for consistency. 

Should those be the ONLY attributes in the classes, or can I have the other styling like font sizes, etc..?

Comment: The css I gave to you should do the job. If nothing is changing, make sure the javascript part works (e.g. add the extra class / remove it )

And yes, you can have other styling in the .topNav selector.. 

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/g8wzs0ry/