# Is there an issue with Chrome/Edge that disallows navbars that change color or go from transparent to opaque?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so in my original question:
 [JavaScript-CSS : Trouble getting Nav Menu to change from transparent to opaque on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202572/javascript-css-trouble-getting-nav-menu-to-change-from-transparent-to-opaque-o/72203446#72203446)

I asked about js/css not working. However, after implementing the answer, trying several online sources, and moving on to actually exporting an example from CodePen.io that was functioning, I am beginning to think something in my browser(s) or computer disallows me from using a sticky top navigation bar that turns from transparent to opaque as the user scrolls.

The reason is that I exported the fully functioning example from CodePen (https://codepen.io/marguerite/pen/aOjKEo) and tried opening the files, only to find that the navbar remained transparent, just as in my original question.

This has played out through several instances of trying to accomplish this with different bits of code. At this point, I am wondering if it's just me or my system or something. Anyone aware of something that would cause this?

**Example**

[image]
[image]

**HTML**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var height = $('.first-container').height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop >= height - 40) {
      $('.nav-container').addClass('solid-nav');
    } else {
      $('.nav-container').removeClass('solid-nav');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 0.125s linear;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 0.125s linear;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first-container {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488831861984-179da3647265?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=938&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  height: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.nav-container.solid-nav {
  background-color: #aaa;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.nav-container .nav-row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.nav-container .nav-row .nav-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav-container .nav-row .nav-controls {
  float: right;
}

.nav-container .nav-row .nav-controls a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-container">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav-row">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <a href="#">
                  Transparent to Solid Nav Row
                </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-controls">
        <a href="#">Item One</a>
        <a href="#">Item Two</a>
        <a href="#">Item Three</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
      Fixed &amp; Transparent Nav
    </h1>
    <p>
      The man in black fled across the desert and the gunslinger followed.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
      Section
    </h1>
    <p>
      The man in black fled across the desert and the gunslinger followed.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>
      Section
    </h1>
    <p>
      The man in black fled across the desert and the gunslinger followed.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Please put your code up as a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help in doing this.

Comment: Your snippet works just fine. What is *NAN/NAV ?* about in your image ? , which OS/browser do you use for testing ?

Comment: @AHaworth That seems to be the problem. The code runs fine if I click "Run Snippet". But, for whatever reason, if I paste the exact same code into an html/css/js file it does NOT display correctly in Chrome, Edge, or Firefox. It's the craziest thing. I do not understand it.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus - The image is the before and after scroll. The poor drawing is actually two images. One with the page unscrolled and the one underneath scrolled. THe red pen shows where the nav bar is, but isn't visible due to a transparent div background with white text in front of a white body background.  However, the transparent background remains. I literally copied the code from a working CodePen example just to test this theory and it turns out that for some very unknown reason it does not work in Chrome, FireFox, or Edge.

Comment: Have a look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility at the console - you will probably see that the jquery is not loading and therefore you have a javascript error - it immediately does not recognise the $ so that code isn't executed - nothing is sensing the scrolling. Try putting a https: at the front of the url loading the script.